# Matching multiple of the same line with Python

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to match multiple blocks of successive similar lines using a regular expression. Precisely, I am attempting to match multiple blocks in a file like

```
H  0  0  0
O  0  0  1
H  0  1  1
```

which appears multiple times in the file with differing values (to those of you who are curious, I am attempting to grab the molecular geometries output by a quantum chemistry geometry optimization program).

I attempted a regular expression like

```
import re
#                 atom      x       y       z
>>> my_re = r'(\s*(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\n)+'
>>> my_string = 'lorem ipsum\nH 0 0 0\nO 0 0 1\nH 0 1 1\nlorem ipsum'
>>> re.findall(my_re, my_string)
[('H 0 1 1\n', 'H', '0', '1', '1')]
```

Instead of matching the whole molecule block, it only matches the last line of the block. If I remove the final `+`, the regex then matches all the lines of the block individually, i.e.

```
[('H 0 0 0\n', 'H', '0', '0', '0'),
 ('O 0 0 1\n', 'O', '0', '0', '1'),
 ('H 0 1 1\n', 'H', '0', '1', '1')]
```

My regex is happy to match successive lines if I duplicate it, e.g.

```
>>> re.findall(my_re*3, a)
[('H 0 0 0\n', 'H', '0', '0', '0',
  'O 0 0 1\n', 'O', '0', '0', '1',
  'H 0 1 1\n', 'H', '0', '1', '1')]
```

Which gives the results that I want, however, I don't know the length of block I need to match ahead of time. How can I fix my regular expression to match multiple successive lines?

Comment: So the problem with your second example, which seems to work, is that you have a list of tuples, instead of just one tuple?  What kind of output do you want?

Comment: I want to match multiple instances of the block, and thus a list of tuples does not tell me which tuples need to be in which block. I would thus like a list of multiple tuples, each tuple corresponding to a block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is that Python's `re` module doesn't handle repeated groups well. If you have a pattern like `"(foo)+"` and match `"foofoofoo"`, the pattern will match the whole string, but only the last of the `"foo"` substrings will be captured.

There are a few ways you might solve this. My first idea is to make a first matching pass without any capturing groups so that you get the whole blocks as strings, then later rematch (with capturing groups) on each block to parse the values from the individual lines:

```
block_re = r'(?:\s*\w+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\n)+' # no groups, findall will yield strings
row_re = r'(\s*(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+))' # you may not want the outer group here
results = [re.findall(row_re, block) for block in re.findall(block_re, my_string)]
```

The `results` variable will be a list of lists of tuples, corresponding to the blocks and the rows within them.

Another way to solve it is to use a fancier regex library. I've not had any personal experience with it, but I've heard that the [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) allows you to repeat groups and still get at all of the captured results. I don't actually know how it works though, so if you go this route you'll have to read the docs or experiment a bit.